# Is it true that $\pi = \lim_{x \to \infty} 10^{x+2}\sin (1.8\times 10^{-x})$? (in degrees)

Tags: limits, trigonometry, pi

When I was doing experiments, I found this shocking results(!). Am I hallucinating? Why I found that the decimal digit expansions of constant $\pi$ is NOTHING MORE than the decimal digit expansions of a sine function.

> I found that
> $$\pi = \lim_{x \to \infty} (10^{x+2}\sin (1.8\times 10^{-x})) \quad\text{(in degrees, not radians)}$$

Is this true?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120908/discussion-on-question-by-antonius-sugianto-is-this-exactly-equal-pi).

Comment: 25.7 radians = ? .   Give me it's value up to 15 digit precision without involving constant $\pi$ at all..

Comment: sorry for my language... Maybe i drank too much coffee and sleep lacking...  :  )

Comment: (Sorry, I think I happened to be writing my comment *as* the comments got moved to chat, so I posted it here by accident...I’ll move/delete it now)

Comment: note the standard limit $lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$

Answer (score 4):

In radians your formula reads:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin{(\pi\cdot 10^{-x-2})}}{10^{-x-2}}=\pi
$$
by the well-known limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin{(ax)}}{x}=a.
$$